# Nvidia: New or the same driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

A few days ago I replaced my Windows by Ubuntu 14 (I have a Dell M15X). After that I notice some random problems with my video card (this was my general impression). Then I installed the latest version of the Nvidia card using:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

After doing that I restarted my computer and I ran:

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

and I got what seems exactly the same configuration:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT216M [GeForce GT 240M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

The only difference from the previous one seems to be

```
driver=nvidia
```

The previous one was

```
driver=nouveau
```

The general problem is that the original card video was GeForce GT 240M and there is no one exactly compatible available in Ubuntu?!

How does it work? Since I installed Ubuntu only few days ago, was it supposed to install this last version? Or not?

Comment: The `nouveau` driver is shipped with Ubuntu, and is non-proprietary. That is, Ubuntu manages updating it. Installing the `nvidia` drivers likely fixed your problem, as those are written and maintained by Nvidia.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10?

Comment: 14.04! I guess you are right. The latest version now is 14.10. I dont know what happened that I used a previous version!?

Answer (score 0):

### Don't do anything!

You installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers and if you [read the xorg-edgers PPA warning again](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) you'll notice that they did warn you that you will receive these.

Currently (January 2015), the [Nouveau Open Software drivers](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) currently [have some problems on some cards](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/) which means that (for the moment) you shouldn't mistake "nouveau" for "better"...

Comment: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)